# Bootstrap collapsible navigation bar not showing links on collapsed window

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap collapsible navigation component that, when collapsed, will show the collapsed icon, but when the icon is clicked, will not display the navigation links.  Can anyone explain to me why this could be happening?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dropdown-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="small-logo">
            <img src="../assets/images/logo_small.png" alt="Logo" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="dropdown-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="nav-left">
            <li class="nav-link dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i>
                    <span>Dashboards</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-link active" id="dashboard" (click)="handleNavigation($event)">
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-facetime-video"></i>Fundus Exams</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-link" id="exams" (click)="handleNavigation($event)">
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i>Exams</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-link dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i>
                    <span>Reporting</span>
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown-link active" id="results" (click)="handleNavigation($event)">
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>Results</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown-link" id="report" (click)="handleNavigation($event)">
                        <a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></i>Result Report</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

While the browser window is full sized, the navigation works the way it's supposed to, but doesn't when it's collapsed.

I would like to mention, I am using Angular 2/4 and Bootstrap 3 to develop this application.  Could that possibly be what the problem is?

Comment: I just noticed that you missed one `(` for the `click` on "Exams" entry. Furthermore, you meant that you can't see sub-items of "Exams" and "Reporting" , or did you mean that you can't toggle the navigation at all in collapsed state? (So you don't even see the "Dashboards" and "Reporting" navigation entries)

Comment: @RamizWachtler Thanks for noticing, that's a typo from making some changes to the code I put in the question.  That's not what breaking it as it's not missing in my working project.  Fixing the typo in the question as that would be something that breaks it.

Comment: Your formatting for the `dropdown` menu doesn't match with what Bootstrap 3 recommends per https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#navbar  ... could this be the problem?

Comment: @RobertC Nope, I matched the documentation, it's still not showing up when the icon is clicked.  I'm updating my question to show my updated markup.

Comment: @Robert Is the whole navigation not displayed or only those sub-items ("Fundus Exams", "Exams" and "Results", "Result Report") ?

Comment: @RamizWachtler when the window is collapsed, none of the navigation is displayed.

Comment: @Robert and when you click the "navbar icon" nothing happens? Have you tried including jQuery?

Comment: @RamizWachtler correct, nothing happens.  I have jQuery included

Comment: Weird, any errors in the console?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161244/discussion-between-ramiz-wachtler-and-robert).

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue, the only thing I did was, in the TypeScript, added a method which toggles the element when the button is clicked.

```
showHide(){
    $("#dropdown-nav").toggle()
}
```

---

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" (click)="showHide()">
    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
```